# mssql 2012 how display specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,
                    CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),101),
                    CONVERT(char(10), fieldname,101))
from tablename
where  isdate(fieldname)=1
```

the output of query is

[image: 111]

how i can display only value like  6 from the result???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),101), CONVERT(char(10), fieldname,101))
FROM lablename
WHERE isdate(fieldname)=1
AND DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),101), CONVERT(char(10), fieldname,101)) = 6
```

**edit 1**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(    SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),101), CONVERT(char(10), fieldname,101)) AS DateDiff
    FROM lablename
    WHERE isdate(fieldname)=1
) A 
WHERE DateDiff = 6
```

Comment: i try this but now i have err
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: updated, try again, also don't mark the answer as accepted when it's not correct, it will block other from helping you as they will thought this is solved.

Comment: i try  the second query that you give me
but i have he same err
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."
how i can fix this err???

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),101), CONVERT(char(10), fieldname,101)) AS DateDiff
    FROM lablename
    WHERE isdate(fieldname)=1
if you only run this part of query will get any error ? which what u did in your question

Comment: it is not work the err say tat have problem whit "welect * from"
the first row of query 
and the err is :
"Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
"

Comment: @jr3d, check your isdate function, it's something wrong there, which normally is caused by month and day were on incorrect position when you doing conversion.

Comment: show my original first question,
the original query is work perfect
but i cant display specific value from the display of query,
how i can display specific value from display of query???

Comment: @jr3d, SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),101), CONVERT(char(10), fieldname,101)) AS DateDiff FROM lablename WHERE isdate(fieldname)=1 this is your original query and you told me it's hitting error, now u say it work perfect again ?